# Delete Parent and child tables without using cascade delete (SQL Server 2012 or .net 4)

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

Working with a SQL Server 2012 database and I need to implement a functionality to allow to delete a row in a table and all it's referenced children based on a foreign key constraint.

Given that `Cascade delete` is out of the question since I cannot touch this database, has anybody written a stored procedure or some code in C# that deletes a parent row and all it's children however deep the children go using 
their foreign keys?

Or a link /article with some pointers?

**Example**

Tables:

1. Customer
2. CustomerAddress
3. CustomerAddress
4. CustomerProducts
5. ProductOrdered

If I decide to delete a customer with an `Id=1`, it should delete

- a row from the `CustomerTable`
- all the rows from `CustomerAddress` with a `customerId=1`
- all `customerProducts` that belong to `CustomerId=1`
- All `ProductOrdered` that belong to that `Customer` with an associated        `customerProductId`

Basically we only have the knowledge of the root table `Customer` and it's `CustomerId` (generic implementation).

Open to any suggestions that does not involve 3rd party tools.

Many thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Are you working with a database of which you don't know the schema? From a point of view of a developer this makes no sense

Comment: You could use metadata from the sql server to generate the querys or build it in C# with SMO. But as Stave said it makes no sense. You bypass all the business rules and just assume it's ok to delete something? If you dont even know the schema how are you suposed to know that it's ok?

Comment: @Steve,I know the schema but I dont own the database it's a client database.And I am not sure about the downvote either.I think you are reading more into it than you should.I didnt want to explain in massive details that than it because unreadable and nobody replies.I tried to be concise.

Answer (score 2):

The basic logic is to remove from the bottom of the hierarchy (the deepest nested) first, and remove references along the way.

If you're using an ORM something like this.

```
foreach(var c in Customer)
{
    var caToClear = c.CustomerAddress().ToList();
    c.CustomerAddress.RemoveAll();
    foreach(var ca in c.caToClear)
    {
        ca.Delete();
    }

    var cpToClear = c.CustomerProducts.ToList();
    c.CustomerProducts.RemoveAll();
    foreach(var cp in cpToClear)
    {
        var poToClear = cp.ProductOrdered.ToList();
        cp.ProductOrdered.RemoveAll();
        foreach(var po in poToClear)
        {
            po.Delete();
        }
        cp.Delete();
    }
    c.Delete();
}
```

To do the same in SQL

```
DELETE FROM productordered 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT product_ordered_id 
              FROM   customerproducts 
              WHERE  customer_id = id_to_delete) 

DELETE FROM customeraddress 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT customer_address_id 
              FROM   customer 
              WHERE  customer_id = id_to_delete) 

DELETE FROM customer 
WHERE  id = id_to_delete
```